# How to convert an array of char into a normal char in C

Tags: c

Lets say I have:

```
char myName[] = "Jason Marks ";
```

And I would like to transfer that into a normal char. The following wouldn't work:

```
char fullName = myName[];
```

How can I make it so that the whole "Jason Marks " gets transferred into the new variable?
And also, is it possible to delete characters from that new variable?

For example, remove the first character and remain with:

```
"ason Marks "
```

Comment: A char can only hold a single character. What you are trying to do doesn't make sense.

Comment: think your confused about what a _char_ is. _char_ type is capable of storing only single characters which is why myname is a char[]. also an _array of char_ is a normal string in c..

Comment: @amdixon Oh ok I get it now. How could I print the whole "Jason Marks " using printf then? When I try to print it, I only get one character using the pointer [location]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to store a string variable in a `char`. Since `char` is capable of holding a single byte, and what you are trying to store is a string of some `n` bytes.

Instead you can use pointer to do this:

```
char array[] = "My Name";
char *ptr = array;
```

Now if you want `"y Name"` only, just increment `ptr` by 1, i.e. `ptr++;` and now if you print `ptr` using `printf` you will get `"y Name"`.

**NOTE :** You can also use `char *ptr = "My Name";`, But the problem is that this will store string `"My Name"` in a **read only location**, i.e. `ptr` will point to a non-modifiable location.
So, in the conclusion, you are not allowed to do anything like this: `ptr[0] = 'B';` however you can do `ptr++;`

**EDIT :** In response to the comment by *Jason Marks*:

You can do that by replacing the last character by a `\0` character, i.e.
`ptr[strlen(ptr) - 1] = '\0';`

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Also, is there a way to erase the letter at the end? For example, get `"My Nam"`

Answer (score 1):

`char` stores a single character, what you need is an array.

Use another char array, and use `strncpy` to copy n characters from source to destination.

```
strncpy(destination, source, length);
```

So in your case you'd do:

```
char fullName[MAX_SIZE];   // Ensure MAX_SIZE >= strlen(myName) + 1,
                           // or dynamically allocate using malloc
                           // with the above size and remember to
                           // free it later.
strncpy(fullName, myName, strlen(myName));
```

---

Now, instead of deleting the first character in the new array, why not copy only what you need?

```
strncpy(fullName, myName + 1, strlen(myName)-1);
                         ^^^ Start from 2nd position, index: 1
```